# Bash and sort files in order

Tags: bash, sorting

with a previous bash script I created a list of files:

```
data_1_box
data_2_box
...
data_10_box
...
data_99_box
```

the thing is that now I need to concatenate them, so I tried

ls -l data_*

but I get

```
.....
data_89_box
data_8_box
data_90_box
...
data_99_box
data_9_box
```

but I need to get in the sucession 1, 2, 3, 4, .. 9, ..., 89, 90, 91, ..., 99

Can it be done in bash?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
ls data_* | sort -n -t _ -k 2
```

-n: sorts numerically
-t: field separator '_'
-k: sort on second field, in your case the numbers after the first '_'

Comment: I have used `sort` for years, never bothered to read the man page - seems I really missed out. Thanks! :-)

Comment: In my case dont sort the files in the right order (linux - bullseye 11) (but ls -lv yes)

Comment: I just tested it in bullseye 11. With the filenames from the question it does work, was your files named differently @EliasEstatisticsEU? See https://pastebin.com/yR139m02

Comment: yes like 1.jpg, 2.jpg... 10.jpg 11.jpg... 20.jpg etc

Comment: My answers separates on '\_', and sorts on the second field. Your files has no '\_', that's why it does not work. To work with your data, use `ls *.jpg| sort -n -t . -k 1` or just `ls *.jpg| sort -n`.

Answer (score 27):

How about using the `-v` flag to `ls`?  The purpose of the flag is to sort files according to version number, but it works just as well here and eliminates the need to pipe the result to `sort`:

```
ls -lv data_*
```

Answer (score 19):

If your `sort` has version sort, try:

```
ls -1 | sort -V
```

(that's a capital V).

Comment: Neat and effective, saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 4):

This is a generic answer! You have to apply rules to the specific set of data

```
ls | sort
```

Example:

```
ls | sort -n -t _ -k 2
```

Comment: -1 ?

I changed to -l, but I do not get the results in that order

Comment: if a try

ls -1 |  sort -n

I get 

...
data_89_box
data_90_box
...
data_99_box
data_9_box
(end)

but i would like them in sequential order

Comment: well the _actual_ is in puppes answer, this was more of a hint to what you need to use.

Comment: I amended my answer to reflect that it was generic in nature.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way to do it in bash if your sort doesn't have version sort:

```
cat <your_former_ls_output_file> | awk ' BEGIN { FS="_" } { printf( "%03d\n",$2) }' | sort | awk ' { printf( "data_%d_box\n", $1)  }'
```

All in one line. Keep in mind, I haven't tested this on your specific data, so it might need a little tweaking to work correctly for you. This outlines a good, robust and relatively simple solution, though. Of course, you can always swap the cat+filename in the beginning with an the actual ls to create the file data on the fly. For capturing the actual filename column, you can choose between correct ls parameters or piping through either cut or awk.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you'll like [SistemaNumeri.py](http://code.google.com/p/unusefulscripts/source/browse/trunk/SistemaNumeri.py) ("fix numbers"): it renames your

```
data_1_box
data_2_box
...
data_10_box
...
data_99_box
```

in

```
data_01_box
data_02_box
...
data_10_box
...
data_99_box
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion I can think of is this :

```
for i in `seq 1 5`
do  
   cat "data_${i}_box"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I have files in a folder and need to sort them based on the number. E.g. -

```
abc_dr-1.txt
hg_io-5.txt
kls_er_we-3.txt
sd-4.txt
sl_rt_we_yh-2.txt
```

I need to sort them based on number.
So I used this to sort.

```
ls -1 | sort -t '-' -nk2
```