# Opposite of Linux Split

Tags: shell, split

I have a huge file and I split the big file into several small chunks and divide and conquer. Now I have a folder contains a list of files like below:

```
output_aa #(the output file done: cat input_aa | python parse.py > output_aa)
output_ab
output_ac
output_ad
...
```

I am wondering is there a way to merge those files back together FOLLOWING THE INDEX ORDER:

I know I could do it by using

```
cat * > output.all
```

but I am more curious another magical command already exist comes with split..

Comment: that's what `cat` is for.

Comment: @Kent You probably meant to say "The output of any program made to stdout can be redirected using append mode with >>" (it's pretty hard to phrase that correct in one sentence I guess)

Comment: then it seems like we just need a command before to make the name keeps the same order

Comment: use "sort" for sorting

Comment: @griffin thx, I read my comment twice, it is hard to understand... `any command/tool (that can read file as input and give output) can do that. with >> redirection. ` this is what I meant

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The magic command would be:

```
cat output_* > output.all
```

There is no need to sort the file names as the shell already does it (*).

As its name suggests, `cat` original design was precisely to conCATenate files which is basically the opposite of `split`.

(*) Edit:

Should you use an (hypothetical ?) locale that use a collating order where the `a-z` order is **not** `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`, here is one way to overcome the issue:

```
LC_ALL=C "sh -c cat output_* > output.all"
```

Comment: Be cautious about sorting - not all shells are needed to sort the same way, and you might also want a different sorting from what the shell provides (that's why my answer mentions the "sort" command) ; see here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747047/bash-and-sort-files-in-order

Comment: @griffin I understand your concern but it shouldn't apply to split output which only uses fixed width 7 bit alphabetical characters.

Comment: Problem with that is that while the POSIX standard needs sort to use a-z as a base26 system, there is no such thing for shells. For example, for bash it's "The sorting order of characters is determined by the current locale and the value of the LC_COLLATE shell variable" - and that, effectively, could be anything.

Comment: @griffin Just did the same for yours as you point out a valid point.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the delimeter when using `cat` ? Something like a equivalent to `paste -d ','`

Comment: @canovasjm `cat` doesn't use any delimiter. `split` doesn't either.

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to concat files together, but there is no magical "opposite of split" in "linux".

Of course, talking about "linux" in general is a bit far fetched, as many distributions have different tools (most of them use a different shell already by default, like sh, bash, csh, zsh, ksh, ...), but if you're talking about debian based linux at least, I don't know of any distribution which would provide such a tool.

---

For sorting you can use the linux command "sort" ;

Also be aware that using ">" for redirecting stdout will override maybe existing contents, while ">>" will concat to an existing file.

---

I don't want to copycat, but still make this answer complete, so what jlliagre said about the cat command should also be considered of course (that "cat" was made to con-"cat" files, effectively making it possible to reverse the split command - but that's only provided you use the same ordering of files, so it's not *exactly* the "opposite of split", but will work that way in close to 100% of the cases (see comments under jlliagre answer for specifics))

Comment: `split` makes sure its output file names are correctly sorted by the shell.