# Concatenating many similar files

Tags: unix, cat

If I have a bunch of files labelled like the following:

```
fasta_Watson_0
fasta_Watson_1
fasta_Watson_2
...
fasta_Watson_190
```

How would I write an awk script to automate concatenating all the files into one?

Hand typing:

```
cat fasta_Watson_0 fasta_Watson_1 ...
```

is just way too tedious!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [bash wildcards](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm), but you'll have to worry about sort order.  Might do something like suggested on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1747099/730138).

```
cat `ls fasta_Watson_* |sort -n -t "_" -k 3`
```

Comment: Only true if the glob sort order gets him the file order he wants. Which may or may not be the case. And is absolutely not the case for the files given in his example as they will sort `0, 1, 10, 11, ..., 2, 20, ..., 3, etc`.

Comment: Why bring `ls` into this instead of just `echo`? Also why the subshell and `cat`?

Comment: Although it really isn't necessary here, `ls -v` on Linux (GNU `ls`) would list the files in the desired order.  The solution is not portable though; `ls -v` has a different meaning on Mac OS X (and no specified meaning according to POSIX).

Answer (score 1):

To `cat` them all in numerical order and save the result in a file named `output`, use:

```
cat fasta_Watson_{0..190} >output
```

The construct `{0..190}` is a bashism representing all numbers from 0 to 190.  If your shell doesn't support that, you can use the standard utility `seq`:

```
cat $(seq -f 'fasta_Watson_%g' 0 190) > output
```

Comment: Or use `cat $(seq -f 'fasta_Watson_%g' 0 190) > output` which uses the `-f` option of `seq` to generate the names explicitly without the shell loop (saving on the number of times `cat` is executed).  This answer (and my variation) depends on the number of files being small enough that the list does not overflow the limit on the length of an argument list to a command.